# How to create promise based action (instead of sendAction) in ember?

Tags: ember.js

I have a use case where the action should get the value from another component, based on that I need to do some actions.
Initially, I used sendAction (instead of promiseAction()) to do some actions. But closeDataModal() runs immediately after finishing the sendAction. I want the first function to finish up and then run the second one.

```
saveAction() {
  promiseAction()
  closeDataModal() -> Run after resolving the promiseAction
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an async function so that you can await an async operation like an async action.

```
async saveAction() {
   await promiseAction()
   closeDataModal() -> will run after resolving the promiseAction
}
```

If you want to use the result of promiseAction then:

```
async saveAction() {
   let result = await promiseAction()
   closeDataModal(result) -> will run after resolving the promiseAction
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, this will not work with sendAction which is deprecated.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function for more infos on how async/await works and how error handling is done.

Comment: This won't work with [`sendAction`-API](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.14/classes/Component/methods/sendAction?anchor=sendAction&show=inherited%2Cdeprecated) cause that one does not return the value. But `sendAction` is [deprecated for reasons](https://deprecations.emberjs.com/v3.x/#toc_ember-component-send-action). You answer will work as soon as the code has been refactored to use a closure action.

Comment: @jelhan Instead of sendAction, is it possible to use promise based action to get a return value?

Comment: @user3652106: You should refactor to closure actions, which have return values. Return a promise from your action. Await the returned promise.